# Azure Data Factory Update Tumbling Window Start time before DevOps deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF with tumbling window trigger. I am using Azure DevOps Release classic pipeline to deploy this ADF pipeline to multiple clients.
I am looking for ways to parameterize the tumbling window trigger start date time so that I can update this before deployment.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tumbling window triggers start date in Azure Data Factory are read-only once published, which means that you cannot edit them directly. You can check this easily in the UI.
[image]

If you need to make changes to a tumbling window trigger, you will need to create a new trigger with the desired changes and delete the old trigger.

There is already a feature request [Changing time on tumbling window triggers](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ed624540-6e26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c), you can submit a vote if you want such a feature.

See the more details from [Unable to edit Tumbling Triggers on Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194008/unable-to-edit-tumbling-triggers-on-azure-data-fac).

Comment: Is there any way to parameterize the start date and set the start date variable before deployment via DevOps?

Comment: Just to clarify, i am not trying to amend the start time for tumbling window trigger of a published pipeline. What i am trying to achieve is the ability to set the start time as a parameter and input this parameter when deploying the adf pipeline via devops release. currently whenever i deploy adf, the tumbling window start time is in the past.

Comment: I noticed that you created a new ticket and mentioned that you were deploying via an ARM template. If so, you can override the value of start time in the [ARM template deployment task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md)  as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77332008/parameterize-azure-data-factory-trigger-start-date).