# Parameterize Azure Data Factory trigger start date

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy ADF to multiple stage at different time. My Pipeline has Tumbling Window Trigger and I would like to parameterize the trigger startTime so that I can set the start time before deploying to avoid backfilling trigger runs.

This is the ARM template i have for the trigger portion. How do i edit this to parameterize the trigger start time.
Thank you.

```
'''

"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers": {
        "properties": {
            "pipelines": [
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "*": "="
                    }
                },
                "pipelineReference.referenceName"
            ],
            "pipeline": {
                "parameters": {
                    "*": "="
                }
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "scope": "="
            }
        }
    },

'''
```

Comment: I can see, you asked the same question twice. [previous question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77327904/azure-data-factory-update-tumbling-window-start-time-before-devops-deployment). Did you check the answer there?

Comment: i did, my question was not answered. i need a way to parameterize the start time when deploying via devops release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring this document [Use custom parameters with the Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters) and this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67667011/16162444), I can complete it with following ARM template.

```
{
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers": {
        "properties": {
            "typeProperties": {
                "startTime": "=:-startTime:string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Steps:

[image]
[image]

It is also in the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` file:

[image]
Result:

[image]

Update:

```
##[error]TumblingWindowTriggerStartTimeUpdateNotAllowed: Start time cannot be updated for Tumbling Window Trigger.
```

To avoid the error, we can add an Azure PowerShell task to stop and delete the trigger before the ARM template deployment task. After deployment, we can also add an Azure PowerShell task to start the trigger.

Sample:

[image]

Azure PowerShell task to stop and delete the trigger:

```
$triggersADF = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Stop-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.name -Force }
$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.name -Force }
```

Azure PowerShell task to start the trigger:

```
$triggersADF = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.name -Force }
```

Related Doc: [Updating active triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-automate-azure-pipelines#updating-active-triggers)